# EF throws exception after second update attempt

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There is an update method throws exception but it works fine in first loging after second attempt throws exception with message;
**

> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type
>   'Hsys.InfluenzaTaniBilgisi' failed because another entity of the same
>   type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when
>   using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

**
Iknow its common and found many smilar issue but I couldnt make it work..

here is code piece;

```
public void CreateUpdateInfluenzaTani(InfluenzaTaniBilgisi taniBilgisi)
            {
                using (HsysDbContext con = new HsysDbContext())
                {

                    if (con.InfluenzaTestTanilari.Any(x => x.ICD10TaniKodu == taniBilgisi.ICD10Kodu && x.IsDeleted != true))
                    {
                        var taniExist = con.InfluenzaTaniBilgisi.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MuayeneId == taniBilgisi.MuayeneId && x.ICD10K

odu == taniBilgisi.ICD10Kodu && x.IsDeleted != true);
                        if (taniExist == null)
                        {
                            taniBilgisi.ObjectState = Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Added;
                            Create(taniBilgisi);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            taniExist.HastaYasi = taniBilgisi.HastaYasi;
                            taniExist.HekimTC = taniBilgisi.HekimTC;
                            taniExist.ObjectState = Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Modified;
                            Update(taniExist);// throws Exception!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What‘s in the Update method?

Comment: Which version of EntityFramework do you use?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the Update-Call. Maybe it's better to not set the ObjectState and call the Update-method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 taniExist.ObjectState = Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Modified;
```

This is your issue.

You cannot use the `Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Modified;` **on an existing key**, **entity frame work won't allow that**.

You need to first do this:

```
taniExist.ObjectState = Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Added;
```

and then:

```
  taniExist.ObjectState = Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Modified;
```

Your code will look like this:

```
      taniExist.HastaYasi = taniBilgisi.HastaYasi;
                            taniExist.HekimTC = taniBilgisi.HekimTC;
                            taniExist.ObjectState = Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Added;
                            Update(taniExist);
Framework.Entities.ObjectState.Modified;
```